# unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm attempting to initialize an array and add a chapter object to an array of book objects, but it crashes with the error:

> 2012-07-25 21:41:01.503 Project1[2364:f803] -[__NSCFString
>   arrayOfChapters]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6ad80b0
>   2012-07-25 21:41:01.505 Project1[2364:f803] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFString arrayOfChapters]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x6ad80b0'

My code:

```
Chapter *myChapter = [[Chapter alloc]init];
myChapter.pageCount = self.TextField2.text;
myChapter.chapterTitle = self.TextField1.text;
if(!currentBook.arrayOfChapters)
{
    currentBook.arrayOfChapters = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
currentBook = [books objectAtIndex:segControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
[currentBook.arrayOfChapters addObject:myChapter];
```

I think the code is correct, is there something set up wrong with my project?  I believe it's the initialization which is causing the actual crash, but there isn't anything non-standard there.

Comment: Where do you declare `arrayOfChapters`?

Comment: In the class Book:

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayOfChapters;

Comment: Do you initialize `currentBook` anywhere before the line `currentBook = [books objectAtIndex:segControl.selectedSegmentIndex];`?

Comment: currentBook is a local variable which is initialized in the line of code on screen - which is just after I check if it's null.  I've moved that line of code above the if statement, but it still crashes with the same error.

Comment: You can't refer to a property (`arrayOfChapters`) of an item that's not, itself, initialized. You want to check `currentBook` before you start using it.

Comment: You aren't checking if `currentBook` is nil, you're checking if `currentBook.arrayOfChapters` returns nil, which is not the same thing.  If moving that line above the if statement doesn't fix the problem, then there is likely something wrong with `books`.  What is `books` (I'm assuming it's an `NSArray`?) and where is it initialized?

Comment: Books is an NSMutableArray which holds chapters, and chapters contain a title and page count.  I added an if(!currentBook) check, and currentBook is non-null.  Is it possible to get in trouble if I'm accidentally double allocing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a breakpoint on the line "`if(!currentBook.arrayOfChapters)`" to check whether the currentBook is nil;

make a breakpoint on the line`"currentBook = [books objectAtIndex:segControl.selectedSegmentIndex];`
" to check whether the segControl.selectedSegmentIndex >= [books count]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like currentBook is a string or not initialized.

Comment: Turns out it was a string - I had originally had a more simple data structure before I added more variables to chapter/book and hadn't gone back and actually created a book where I thought I had one...

Answer (score 0):

I may be misreading this but...

```
    if(!currentBook.arrayOfChapters)
    {
        // creating array for current book
        currentBook.arrayOfChapters = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
    }

    // reassigning a new book to current book. Are you sure this new one has array of chapters?
    currentBook = [books objectAtIndex:segControl.selectedSegmentIndex]; 

    // trying to access array of chapters
    [currentBook.arrayOfChapters addObject:myChapter];
```

Shouldn't you be assigning first and then creating array if it's not already there?

Comment: Yes, I should, and I did make that change, although that wasn't what caused the crash.  CurrentBook was completely lying, it was actually a string which I set entirely incorrectly elsewhere.